# How to retrieve a list of cells with a specific value from a column, and display the text content of another column into another sheet?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spices "Inventory" sheet with Column A "Product" and Column B "Stock". I would like to retrieve the names of the spices from "Product" based on a certain stock value from "Stock", say 0, or any other criteria (<=5), and display the names of the pices from "Product" into another sheet.

```
      A              B
1  Product         Stock
2  Cinnamon          3
3  Cassia            0
4  Fennel            1
5  Aniseed           0
6  Star Anise        0
7  Liquorice         1
8  Clove             7
9  Allspice          0
10 Vanilla           1
11 Tonka bean        1
```

I have tried a combination of INDEX MATCH and it does work partially but not in the concise and clean way I was expecting. THis is my formula so far:

=INDEX(Inventory!A2:A11,MATCH(0,Inventory!B2:B11,0))

And this is what I get when I drag the formula down to extend the selection:

```
         D
1  No Stock Prods
2  Cassia
3  Cassia
4  Aniseed
5  Aniseed
6  Star Anise
7  Allspice
8  Allspice
9  Allspice
10 #N/A
11 #N/A
```

So it does bring those entries with value 0, but it keeps retrieving the same values as the formula moves down the sheet until it finds another match, and so on.

This is what I want, only the names of products with stock 0, without repeating names or errors:

```
         D
1  No Stock Prods
2  Cassia
3  Aniseed
4  Star Anise
5  Allspice
```

Comment: Does your version f Excel support the *aggregate()* worksheet function ??

Comment: Can you use helper columns?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent it does support aggregate(), as it works a treat. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I would also like to use another condition for the function to meet. Let's say I add another column "Category" next to "Stock" being the entries "Sweet", "Earthy", etc. How can I combine the INDEX solution you provided with another function? Would the IF function work and how to insert it in the solution you provide? Should I start another thread?

Comment: I will examine the issue tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

To get the values equivalent to **0** in column **B**, in **D1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$999)/($B$1:$B$11=0),ROW(1:1)),),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

To use a different criteria, just replace the factor:

```
($B$1:$B$11=0)
```